# css 100% width iphone

Tags: iphone, css, responsive-design

I am having a rough time with responsive design on this one site.  Don't know what is happening, and my code has kind of turned to crap as a result, this is a modified zurb foundation grid, however the client wanted left navigation.  Once the design drops to an iphone for some reason the width of the top elements (logo, menu) has some margin, padding or is only approx 80% width.  See http://eseamedia.com/lm

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { 

.menu {
    background: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    float: none; }

.menu nav {
    height: auto;
    margin :0 auto 26px auto;
    width: 100% }

.menu ul li a {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align:center; }

.logo {
    background-position: center center;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin 0;
    height: 104px;
    width: 321px;
    padding: 0 }

.info {
    position:relative }

.headline{
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
    padding:0;}

.context, .wrap {
    margin:0;
    left:0;}
}
```

Comment: Just curious but why are you setting the display property for .menu to table? If it were a block element, you wouldn't need to set a max-width or min-width as long as you don't have a float set.

Answer (score 5):

use meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: this is perfect '<meta http-equiv="Content-type" name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">'